# How to draw bitmap image on top in arc

Tags: java, android, canvas, android-canvas

I want to draw image on Top in each Arc of Canvas

```
 private void drawImage(Canvas canvas, float tempAngle, Bitmap bitmap,String mValue) {
    //get every arc img width and angle
    int imgWidth = (radius / mWheelItems.size());
    //int imgWidth = (radius / 3);
    float angle = (float) ((tempAngle + 360 / mWheelItems.size() /2) * Math.PI / 180);
    //calculate x and y
    int x = (int) (center + radius / 2 / 2 * Math.cos(angle));
    int y = (int) (center + radius / 2 / 2 * Math.sin(angle));

    int top=y - imgWidth/2;
    int bottom=y +imgWidth/2;

    int left=x - imgWidth /2;
    int right=x + imgWidth / 2;

        Rect rect = new Rect(left, top, right, bottom);

                final Rect rect1 = new Rect(x - imgWidth /2 , y - imgWidth / 2  , bitmap.getWidth() , bitmap.getHeight());

   canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap, null, rect, null);
}
```

the Arc is made according to the size of items

The Result is shown like that

[image]

But I want the image bitmap shown on top like that of rect. Red also want to large size of images or bitmap

[image]

Comment: Please read it before downvote

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved by Specific Tab and Big Screen Tablets

Change the X and Y coordination According to Angle

```
if(tempAngle==0) {
        x = x + 50;
    }

    if(tempAngle==60) {
        y = y + 50;
    }
    if(tempAngle==120) {

        imgWidth = imgWidth-12;
        y = y + 20;
        x = x - 40;
    }
    if(tempAngle==180) {
        imgWidth = imgWidth+12;
        x = x - 50;
    }
    if(tempAngle==240) {
        y = y - 50;
    }
    if(tempAngle==300) {
        y = y - 20;
        x = x + 40;
    }
```